# Project Tango - AD to SOS frame pair - unexpected rotation?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to use the coordinate frame pair START_OF_SERVICE to AREA_DEFINITION, post localisation to the AD. I'd expect this to allow me to reconcile the original SOS origin to a proper location, and I'd like to use the incoming data in the posedata.

My test process is to create the ADF by centering my device in my area at a known position in the world with a known orientation in the world, then creating the ADF file. when I run my test app, if I provide a unity world-space offset that matches my ADF origin, everything looks exactly as expected. E.g. if I create my ADF origin at 0,1,0 (unity WS coordinates) by centering the physical device at 0,0 in my ground plane and 1m up in the Y axis, it matches what I'd expect in my Unity scene given a starting AD frame offset of 0,1,0.

If I then start the device at exactly the same real-world position such that the SOS frame should exactly match the AD frame, when the app localises to the AD, I get a translation of (close to) zero, but a rotation of 90 degrees around the Z axis in the quaternion.

As both the base and target frame share the same coordinate space, I'd expect the translation and rotation, given a SOS origin that matches pretty-accurately with the AD origin, to be a zero offset and an identity matrix.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the relocalization basically gives you a 90 degree rotation on roll axis? In the first testing you mentioned (with defined offset), is that running pure motion tracking? I tend to believe this is an application level bug here, no matter how you record the ADF or rotate device. ADF coordinate is alway gravity aligned..

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'm work on the assumption it's at my end and see if I can track down the issue.